# Error de configuración "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms"

Tags: nuget

Cuando compilo la aplicación todo bien pero cuando se inicia, me muestra un error:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. Error de configuración
> Descripción: Error durante el procesamiento de un archivo de
> configuración requerido para dar servicio a esta solicitud. Revise los
> detalles de error específicos siguientes y modifique el archivo de
> configuración en consecuencia.
>
> Mensaje de error del analizador: No se puede cargar el archivo o
> ensamblado 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' ni una de sus
> dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide
> con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Error de código fuente:
>
> Línea 75:       
> Línea 76:  Línea 77:
> assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" /> Línea 78:
>  Línea 79:
>
> Archivo de origen: C:\HSO\InformesBI\Admin\web.config    Línea: 77
>
> Rastro al cargar el ensamblado: La información siguiente puede ser
> útil para determinar porqué no se cargó el ensamblado
> 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'.

en cambio en el archivo dll, la version que tengo es la 10.0.0.0...
no se si eso sea un impedimento de que por eso no me ejecute bien la app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te doy pautas para resolver el problema, supongo que la solución lo trajiste de otra pc, ahí el origen de la mayor parte de errores de este tipo:

1. Entra a la carpeta Bin y obj y borra los elementos y vuelve a compilar.
2. Si tienes instalado el ReporViewer referencia manualmente la dll
3. Instala la misma versión de Visual Studio del cuál se creo el proyecto, esto para asegurarse que tienes la misma versión de ReportViewer y la correcta.
4. Instala la versión de ReportViewer correcta, a continuación la versión 2015. Así lo instalas manualmente

[https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=45496][1]

[1]: ReportViewer 2015

Comment: La de la versión de visual studio era la buena. Sí había descargado el codigo de un repositorio y no recordaba la version del IDE